# Unable to get onClick working in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-preferences

I'm a beginner when it comes to fragments. I have looked through pretty much all of the Stackoverflow questions/anwsers on using onClick inside fragments but for some reason my onClick doesn't get triggered at all.

I have an `AdminActivity` which loads a `SettingsFragment` which extends the `PreferenceFragment`.

AdminActivity.java

```java
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.admin);

    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.settings_fragment, new SettingsFragment())
        .commit();
}
```

admin.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:name="{package_name}.SettingsFragment" android:id="@+id/settings_fragment"
              class="{package_name}.SettingsFragment"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The `SettingsFragment` programatically loads in preference XML layouts and one of the layouts contains a `PrefernceScreen` which has a `Preference` with a layout set to another fragment:

```xml
<PreferenceScreen
    android:key="button_app_updates"
    android:title="App updates"
    android:persistent="false">
    <Preference 
        android:fragment="{package_name}.SettingsUpdateFragment"
        android:layout="@layout/settings_update_fragment" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

This now loads a new `PreferenceFragment` which allows the app to be updated (this is an itnernally distributed app that will not be uploaded to Play Store)

```java
public class SettingsUpdateFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener

private TextView updateStatus;
private ProgressBar updateProgress;
private Button updateAction;
private TextView lastUpdated;
```

In `onCreateView` I define the views for the variables from the layout as well as set the button up with a `OnClickListener`

```java
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.settings_update_fragment, container, false);
    updateStatus = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.updateStatus);
    updateProgress = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.updateProgress);
    updateAction = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.updateAction);
    lastUpdated = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lastUpdated);

    Iconify.addIcons(updateAction);
    updateAction.setOnClickListener(this);

    return view;
}
```

The `onClick` is taken from the `View.OnClickListener` implementation of `SettingsUpdateFragment`

```java
@Override
public void onClick(View view){
    if(hasUpdates){
        Log.d(TAG, "updateAction triggered for downloadAndInstall()");
        downloadAndInstall();
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "updateAction triggered for checkForUpdates()");
        checkForUpdates();
    }
}
```

For some reason the onClick never gets triggered. `hasUpdates` by default is `false` so atleast `checkForUpdates()` method should get triggered.

I also tried creating the `View.OnClickListener` for the button inline

```java
updateAction.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(hasUpdates){
            Log.d(TAG, "updateAction triggered for downloadAndInstall()");
            downloadAndInstall();
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "updateAction triggered for checkForUpdates()");
            checkForUpdates();
        }
    }
});
```

but that did not work as well.

Have I overlooked something? Is something wrong of how I implemented the `PreferenceFragment` or is it something else?

**Update**

After doing some debugging with `Log` I found out that the `Fragment` isn't even getting created.

**Minor update**

I have a feeling that the `Preference` from my XML is only recognising the `android:layout` but not the `android:fragment`. I tried removing the `layout` and only left in `fragment` and then it doesn't display the layout defined in `SettingsUpdateFragment::onCreateView()`.

I added a debug log entry to the `Fragment`s `onCreate()` and the log line doesn't get ever displayed. So the issue seems to be that the `Fragment` isn't being loaded from the `Preference`. But why?

Comment: 1. Remove try ,catch block from mapping of all view 

2. What is Iconify?

Comment: @AvishekDas [Iconify](https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-iconify) is a library to integrate FontAwesome icons in an android application. I removed the try/catch block but had no effect however I did find out that `Fragment` itself doesn't even get loaded. Check the updated question please.

Comment: now try with this way 

updateAction.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Image Clicked",
      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
  });

And remove the OnclickListner from implements

Comment: @AvishekDas I have a feeling that the issue might be in the `Fragment` not loading at all. The `Preference` in my XML for some reason is ignoring the `fragment` attribute and only recognising the `layout` attribute. I tested by removing `android:layout` and the layout defined in `SettingsUpdateFragment::onCreateView()` is not displayed. I also added this info the the question.

Comment: Oo you have to use FrameLayout..

Comment: Like this 

<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/dashboard_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/rl_footer"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ll_dashboard_header"
        android:paddingBottom="60dp"
        android:paddingTop="80dp" />

Comment: @AvishekDas First of all thank-you for you quick responses on the question but I think you have misunderstood the issue. In some of the new updates I pointed out that issue does not seem to be in the layout but the fact that the Fragment is not getting created from `Preference`'s `android:fragment` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

"....extends `PreferenceFragment` ...."

and

```
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.settings_update_fragment, container, false);
```

this looks somehow not right. If it's not preference fragment, do not extend it as preference fragment. or use `addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);`.

may be it's not the problem, but still looks suspicious.

Comment: I actually had it extending just `Fragment` thinking that might have been the issue but unfortunately that did not have any effect on it.

Answer (score 0):

Your admin.xml will be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/settings_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to make attribute `android:fragment` of the `Preference` tag working, your hosting activity must implement [`PreferenceFragment.OnPreferenceStartFragmentCallback`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.OnPreferenceStartFragmentCallback.html)

```
class AdminActivity extends Activity
    implements PreferenceFragment.OnPreferenceStartFragmentCallback
{
    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceStartFragment(PreferenceFragment caller, Preference pref)
    {
        try
        {
            Fragment f = (Fragment) Class.forName(pref.getFragment()).getConstructor().newInstance();
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.settings_fragment, f).addToBackStack(null).commit();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }
...
```